Using "replace" in C++
I am getting a string that is for example "3+2+1" and I need to sort the numbers so the program prints "1+2+3." I first take out the numbers from the string and store them in temp then sort them, now have temp which is 123. After sorting I need to replace the original "3+2+1" with "1+2+3." I am using replace wrong.

int main() {
    string original, temp;
    cin>>original;

    for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); i++) {
        if (original[i] != '+') {
            temp.push_back(original[i]);
        }
    }

    sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    cout<<temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); i++) {
        if (i = 0){
            original.replace(original[i], 1, temp[i]);
        }
        if (original[i] != '+') {
            original.replace(original[i],1,temp[i-1]);
        }
    }
    return 0;

}


@Someprogrammerdude: it sounds like the requirement is to sort the numbers, not necessarily reverse them.

It would probably be easier to build a new string, adding sorted numbers and + characters to the end in alternation, than to modify an existing string in-place

temp[i-1] - this is wrong. temp[4-1] reads the null character. You should use temp.front() and temp.pop_front() as an opposite to temp.push_back().

What should this program do with inputs like 11+21+12?

Two vectors then: One for the numbers, one for the operators. Sort the numbers, and print out one number, one operator, one number, etc.

if (i = 0){ won't do what you expect, you want if (i == 0){ (and turn your warnings to spot that issue).

"I am using replace wrong." -- Why do you think this? (What is your actual output? Or does your code not compile? There are many ways to do things wrong, and different symptoms for them.) If it is just using replace, then you should be able to skip your assignment and create a 3-line [mre]: initialize a string, call replace, and output the (wrong) result.

Can numbers be greater than 9? What about negative numbers? Whitespace? Your spec is missing some info.

Also, obligatory "please read this".

There's no point in using replace when you're just overwriting one character with one other character.

Why are you using replace() at all?   Once you have sorted temp, simply clear original and then write the elements of temp to it in order, separated by +.   Among other things, this will correctly handle "21+11+23" which your approach (even if you get it working correctly) cannot since it implicitly assumes single-digit values.

There's a few things wrong with your code besides the replace function that you have implemented that can also mess up your result. In the future, I suggest you use a debugger or a debugging method to check your code first.
Problems that you have:

if (i = 0){
This does not do what you this it does. If you want to check if i is 0, you need to write i == 0. Just one = sign will assign i to be 0 every time, so you get stuck in an infinite loop.

if (original[i] != '+') {
This if statement can be problematic. I understand that you are trying to separate the i == 0 case, but if the first character in your string is not a + as well, this statement will still run and mess up your code as you try to access temp[-1].

original.replace(original[i], 1, temp[i]);
original.replace(original[i],1,temp[i-1]);
You see, the replace function is structured like this: string& replace( pos, cont, str); For this function, first parameter is an integer with the index of the starting location for where you want to replace. That means that you shouldn't put original[i], which gives a character, but instead just use i. This will correctly replace your character. Also, the last parameter should be a string, not a character, so just put your character into the to_string() function will be easiest.


With the problems above in mind, this is your corrected code using the replace function:
int main() {
    string original, temp;
    cin >> original;
    for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); i++) {
        if (original[i] != '+') {
            temp.push_back(original[i]);
        }
    }
    sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    cout<<temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0){
            original.replace(i, 1, to_string(temp[i]));
        }
        else if (original[i] != '+') {
            original.replace(i, 1, to_string(temp[i-1]));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


std::string::replace is really unsuitable for what you are trying to do. You are trying to replace one character at a time, so use assignment.
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < original.size(); i++) {
    if (original[i] != '+') {
        original[i] = temp[j];
        j++;
    }
}

Because there are no + characters in temp you need to advance it only when the character in original wasn't a +, thus there are two indexes in the loop.
As the commenters note, this will work only when the input is only single digit numbers and +, if there are multiple digit numbers, or spaces, then the result will (most likely) be a sum with a different total.
